# I am using Cufon hack Cufon.now() on wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, fonts, cufon

I am trying to use Cufon on my wordpress, to stop the delayed appearance, I am trying to use the Cufon.now() hack withing my page but its not working, i am using FireFox 3.5.7 for testing purpose, Can someone point me out where I am going wroong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to use the hack properly across all browsers , so I didnt display the elements on which i was using the custom fonts, until the document was ready, not exactly a workaround but the delayed appearance wasn't looking awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

.cufon-loading class

Similar to cufon-active, but only available when the document and/or CSS style sheets are still loading. This makes it possible to hide elements while they’re still waiting for their turn to be processed:

.cufon-loading h1 { /* for Cufon.replace('h1') */
    visibility: hidden !important;
}